# css transition max-height back to 0 not working

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have a simple div which has height and max-height set to 10px. When I hover over it, it should expand to the full height of div and when I leave it should shrink back to 10px.

But the when I unhover, the code below won't transit smoothly back to 0.

HTML

```
<div class="animate">
   Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory  ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.
</div>
```

CSS

```
.animate{
  font-size:20px;
  height : 10px;
  max-height:10px;
  width: 100px;
  overflow:hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.animate:hover{
  height:auto;
  max-height:1000px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3hfxg6he/2/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Remove `height:10px;` from your code. it ll makes height 10px in high priority and makes overflow-hidden. thats why the animation is not working. for more details about `max-height` property follow [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-height)

```css
.animate{
  font-size:20px;
  max-height:10px;
  width: 100px;
  overflow:hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.animate:hover{
  height:auto;
  max-height:1000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="animate">
Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory  ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe `max-height: none;` rather than `1000px`?

Comment: it wont animate the div. as the transition wouldn't know how much it should animate. we should give some `max-height` value

Comment: Ah, that's really helpful to know. Thank you!

Comment: Accept and upvote if it really helps. so that it would be helpful to find solution for someone like you

Comment: I can't accept, because this isn't my question ;-) But I have upvoted. :-D

Comment: k k ... :D NP chill ;)

Comment: `max-height` is supposed to override `height`, so not sure what you mean with height has "high priority". https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-height

Comment: @Michael_B but overriding occurs only when the height exceeds the the `max-height` value. but here he only given minimum value to it as `10px` which is lower than `max-height` property of the `:hover`. thats why we have to remove it