# CSS Transitions and animations not working

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-animations

I am trying to implement a animation where if user clicks a label, the (originally hidden) div will open from top to bottom, and if they click it again the div will close nicely from bottom to top.

```css
/* Firstly I tried using css transitions but it does not work 
at all as the entire div just opened without as transition*/
input.trigger+div.mapInfo {
  display: none; /* div originally hidden */
  height: 0px;
  max-height: 0px;
  transition: all 300ms;
}

input.trigger:checked+div.mapInfo {
  display: block;/*div shown*/
  height: auto;
  max-height: 500px;
}

/*Then I tried using max-height,min-height, and height for 
transitions but it still doesn't work*/

input.trigger + div.mapInfo{
   display:none;
   min-height:0px;
   max-height:0px;
   transition:all 300ms;
}




input.trigger:checked + div.mapInfo{
   display:block;
   min-height:300px;
   max-height:500px;
   height:auto;
}


/*Hence, I deleted the transition code and tried css 
animations now the div opens up nicely  but still closed 
without animations*/
input.trigger+div.mapInfo {
  display: none;
  animation: close-up 300ms linear forwards;/*this line of code appears to be not working*/
}

input.trigger:checked+div.mapInfo {
  display: block;
  animation: open-up 300ms linear forwards;
}

@keyframes close-up {
  0% {
    max-height: 500px;
  }
  100% {
    max-height: 0px;
  }
}

@keyframes open-up {
  0% {
    max-height: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    max-height: 500px;
  }
}
/* Further more I tried using transform:scaleY() and 
replacing the max-height, but closing the div still has no animations */
@keyframes close-up{
0%{
   transform:scaleY(1)
}
   100%{
   transform:scaleY(0);
}
}
@keyframes open-up{
   0%{
transform:scaleY(0);
   }
   100%{
transform:scaleY(1);
   }
}
```

```html
<!-- the label that user clicks on -->
<label id="marker6" class="battleMarkers" for="trigger6"><img src="ss_marker.png" alt="" /></label>

<input class="trigger" type="checkbox" id="trigger6">
<!-- the div to be opened-->
<div class="mapInfo" id="info6">
  <h2>Sword Beach</h2>
  <p>Sword was the easternmost landing site of the Normandy Invasion. Sword was divided into several sectors with each sector divided into beaches. Sword is located about 9 miles from Caen, the goal of the 3rd Infantry Division.</p>
  <p>The Sword landing suffered few casualties but it's route inland suffered from traffic congestion that limited the invasion's effectiveness. Troops at Sword experienced the only armour counter-attack of D-Day, mounted by the 21st Panzer Division.</p>
</div>
```

Note: This question is different from `[this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40850869/css-transition-max-height-back-to-0-not-working/40850960) as his/her div has a starting height of 10px while mine is hidden from the start.

Comment: Would you mind using JS or are you set on using CSS?

Comment: @jacc_01 is the JS very difficult/confusing? Now I know some js basics like variable data type loops ,functions

Comment: I noticed your question said for the div to open from top to bottom but the code you tried does it from bottom to top. Top to bottom is much easier and both answers provided already let you do this. If you do in fact want bottom to top then you'll need JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you want to do. But I just changed the transition instead of going for the display, I changed the text color. You can also use visibility if you are going to add images. Accroding to W3schools.com, display property is not animatable. That is why when you uncheck the box it immediately goes to `display:none` without transition effect.

```css
input.trigger+div.mapInfo {
  display:hidden; /* div originally hidden */
  color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
  height: 0px;
  overflow:hidden;
  transition:1s;
}

input.trigger:checked+div.mapInfo {
  display: block;/*div shown*/
  color:rgba(0,0,0,1);
  height: 500px;
  transition:1s;
}
```

```html
<!-- the label that user clicks on -->
<label id="marker6" class="battleMarkers" for="trigger6"><img src="ss_marker.png" alt="" /></label>

<input class="trigger" type="checkbox" id="trigger6">
<!-- the div to be opened-->
<div class="mapInfo" id="info6">
  <h2>Sword Beach</h2>
  <p>Sword was the easternmost landing site of the Normandy Invasion. Sword was divided into several sectors with each sector divided into beaches. Sword is located about 9 miles from Caen, the goal of the 3rd Infantry Division.</p>
  <p>The Sword landing suffered few casualties but it's route inland suffered from traffic congestion that limited the invasion's effectiveness. Troops at Sword experienced the only armour counter-attack of D-Day, mounted by the 21st Panzer Division.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Huge thanks to you! After modifying your code I manage to get what I want!!

Answer (score 0):

The minimum thing you need to do to make it work is change the height. Be sure you also set overflow to hidden.

```css
/* Firstly I tried using css transitions but it does not work 
at all as the entire div just opened without as transition*/

.mapInfo {
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 300ms;
}

.trigger:checked ~ .mapInfo {
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<!-- the label that user clicks on -->
<label id="marker6" class="battleMarkers" for="trigger6"><img src="ss_marker.png" alt="" /></label>

<input class="trigger" type="checkbox" id="trigger6">
<!-- the div to be opened-->
<div class="mapInfo" id="info6">
  <h2>Sword Beach</h2>
  <p>Sword was the easternmost landing site of the Normandy Invasion. Sword was divided into several sectors with each sector divided into beaches. Sword is located about 9 miles from Caen, the goal of the 3rd Infantry Division.</p>
  <p>The Sword landing suffered few casualties but it's route inland suffered from traffic congestion that limited the invasion's effectiveness. Troops at Sword experienced the only armour counter-attack of D-Day, mounted by the 21st Panzer Division.</p>
</div>
```